# Wordpress - run php functions if user is subscriber/contributor

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am experimenting and creating my first Wordpress site, and this is my first stack overflow question :)

My end goal is to hide the Personal Options for subscribers/contributors in their profile page.  It's just clutter that gets in the way.

I found this code written by someone who had a similar problem, and slightly edited it to make it work for me:

```
function remove_opt_start($adddiv) {
$gettitle = array('#<h2>Personal Options</h2>#');
$adddiv = preg_replace($gettitle, '<div class="hidden">', $adddiv,1);
return $adddiv;
}

function start_remove_opt_start() { ob_start("remove_opt_start"); }

function end_remove_opt_start() { ob_end_flush(); }

function remove_opt_end($addend) {
$getname = array('#<h2>Name</h2>#');
$addend = preg_replace($getname, '</div><h2>Name</h2>',$addend,1);
return $addend;
}

function start_remove_opt_end() { ob_start("remove_opt_end"); }

function end_remove_opt_end() { ob_end_flush(); }

add_action('admin_head','start_remove_opt_start');
add_action('admin_head','start_remove_opt_end');
add_action('admin_footer','end_remove_opt_start');
add_action('admin_footer','end_remove_opt_end');

?>
```

And it's great!  But it also removes the options for admins, editors, and authors, which I do not want.  So I found this code where someone was attempting to distinguish between users:

```
global $current_user; 
get_currentuserinfo();
switch (true)  {
 case ( user_can( $current_user, "subscriber") ):
   // Show Role
   // Show Subscriber Image
 break;
 case ( user_can( $current_user, "contributor") ):
   // Show Role
   // Show Contributor Image
 break;
 case ( user_can( $current_user, "administrator") ):
   // Show Role
   // Show Administrator Image
 break;
}
```

So basically, my question is thus:
How do I have combine the two codes so that the first code block is only called when the second code block detects that a user is a contributor or subscriber.

I was hoping it could be as simple as coping and pasting it inside the commented area, but it never is quite that easy.  Unfortunately, I have very little knowledge of php, but I'm excited to learn :)

Comment: Update:  I tried copying and pasting the first code block into the comment section of the second code block, moved around the ?> until a php syntax checker said it was good to go, and it totally crashed my site so that nothing is showing up.

Comment: Update 2:  Completely failed trying to resolve the white screen of death.  Going to delete database and wipe server and start again.  I guess I learned two things:  backups and not to edit functions.php on a whim.  This means that I'll try to wrap the code above in a wordpress plugin that would only affect the profile.php page.

Comment: Update 3: Fixed the website and content, and I'm giving the code another go! :)